# Razor DropDown helpers with null passed for the SelectListItems uses ViewBag by convention?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-6

The following Razor

```
@Html.DropDownList("FloorId", null)
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FloorId, null)
```

picks up the select list items from my Entity Framework models, using the foreign key. In the foreign entity I happen to have a property called `Name` which is being used for the `Text`, and the `Id` is being used for the `Value`.

This appears to be voodoo.

How is this wired up? Are there any conventions to be followed? Was it pure luck that I had an `Id` and `Name` property?

I can see in the controller that the `ViewBag` has the select list added but there's nowhere that the select list is then added to the DropDown list; other than by having an `Id` matching the `ViewBag` property.

---

*Edit to Add models*

```
public class Floor
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Floor")]
    public int FloorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Floor Floor { get; set; }
}
```

If you scaffold this, the controller has:

```
ViewBag.FloorId = new SelectList(db.Floor, "Id", "Name", room.FloorId);
```

And the above Razor. I can only assume that if no `SelectList` is given to a `DropDownList` or `DropDownListFor` that it will fall back and use the `ViewBag` property of the same `Id` for it's select list?

Comment: Can you show the relevant entity classes, how you actually call `DropDownList(For)` and what the generated HTML looks like?

Comment: @CodeCaster it's literally scaffolded in Visual Studio with nothing else added. I'll add the models to show

Comment: Yeah sure, but I've never seen `@Html.DropDownList` grab random entities from nowhere. I mean why spend 200 reputation if you can spend a little more effort to make the question complete first. :)

Answer (score 3):

> I can only assume that if no SelectList is given to a DropDownList or DropDownListFor that it will fall back and use the ViewBag property of the same Id for it's select list?

Yes. That's one of the many handy conventions in MVC that you can only find out by digging through the source or old blog posts, and which is not mentioned explicitly in the documentation.

See [Using the DropDownList Helper with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc):

> you can pass the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` explicitly to the DropDownList helper or you can add the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to the ViewBag **using the same name for the SelectListItem as the model property**

And in the [source](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs):

```
private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectData(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name)
{
    object o = null;
    if (htmlHelper.ViewData != null)
    {
        o = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(name);
    }
    if (o == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            String.Format(
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                MvcResources.HtmlHelper_MissingSelectData,
                name,
                "IEnumerable<SelectListItem>"));
    }

    // ...

    return selectList;
}
```

I for one don't think you should rely on conventions like this, however easy it is to let the code be scaffolded like this. Instead use a proper ViewModel that contains the items for your dropdowns.

Comment: I had found that article, but couldn't verify anything in any documentation anywhere, hence asking the question. It seems that MVC has some conventions scattered around without any clear guidance or consistency

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same name as Your properties while using html helpers
For E.g in your case

```
ViewBag.FloorId = new SelectList(db.Floor, "Id", "Name", room.FloorId);
```

If you use FloorId in HtmlHelpers Like u did

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FloorId, null)
```

It will automatically assume ViewBag property is meant for this DropDown as it has common name

Comment: The OP is asking how this works and where it is documented.

Comment: I found this in a tutorial.